# Areca Palms Keep Dying on Me

Tags: plant-care

This is my 3rd Areca and no matter what I do, the plant keeps dying on me, it's saddening and frustrating!

- The leaves are turning brown from the tip, others are drying. Some, however, are still fine. The wilting is concentrated at the back of the plant (leaves facing the wall)
- I only water (1-1.5 L) when the soil dries out, that's like once a week or 10 days. I use bottled water.
- No spider mites apparent, no diseases either I don't think
- I am a smoker, if that's a factor
- The plant was repotted
- The room is AC-ed, the temps go down to about 20C, cool air does hit the plant
- The plant is placed near an electricity outlet (harmful?)
- The plant gets moderate sunlight as it is sitting in a corner

Any tips would help. I really don't want this Areca to completely die on me.

Photos
[image]

Comment: Pictures please

Comment: My guess is the AC, it makes the humidity dry, probably to dry for this species.

Comment: any pests would be on the underside of the leaves. Take a close look for spider mites that look like grains of salt and let us know